# Blanket.JS doesn't generate a report in Mocha

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, backbone.js, mocha.js, blanket.js

On the [Blanket.JS website](http://blanketjs.org/) it is said that Mocha is supported. I followed the procedure of including blanket.js on my test page and put the data-cover attribute on the appropriate script elements but no report of coverage is being shown on the generated test page.

I have only 2 unit tests: 1 for a Backbone.js Model and 1 for a Backbone.js Collection. Can somebody assist me in getting the code coverage report?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, to solve this problem you need to include mocha-blanket.js, also.